# Is this JSON correct?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, validation

How can I validate this JSON and add placeholders for the columns in SQL table?

```
[ 
  {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'}, 
  {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'}, 
  {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'}, 
  {name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'}, 
  {name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'}, 
]
```

Comment: What you mean by "placeholders for the columns in SQL table" is utterly unclear. [Edit] the question and add a [example].

Comment: SQL is just a language used within DB Management Systems, you should share with us name of your DBMS product in order to get an exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must use quotes also for field names. There are plenty of JSON validators and formatters online where you can test the syntax of your JSON data (e.g. https://jsonformatter.org/).

```
[
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"},
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},
  {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to JSON and still learning. Do you know how I can add a placeholder for all objects in this file without doing it manually?

Comment: What do you consider a placeholder in this file ? You mean replacing name: with "name": ? In this case, you can use any text editor. Or you can use the file you find here: https://gist.github.com/keeguon/2310008#gistcomment-869598